# Canceling accidental checkout that you know is going to take a while

Tags: git, visual-studio

I mostly develop in Visual Studio, but I run all my git commands in Git Bash (except for view history and looking at commits). Today I accidentally clicked on the branch selector at the bottom right of Visual Studio and changed the branch. I didn't even know what branch I had selected, until I saw it start the checkout process and was dismayed to see "Checking out files (100/52,000)". I had accidentally selected a very old branch. I thought for a moment and decided I probably should just let it finish, which is what I did, and then I switched back when it was done. This set me back more than 5 minutes.

Is there something better I could have done as soon as I realized it? Visual Studio (2017) pretty much locks up at that point. I know I could have killed VS, but I was concerned about what state I would have left my repo in had I done that.

If just waiting it out is the best option, had I checked out an old branch from the command line instead (say, in git bash), would the answer be any different?

Comment: I guess you could have killed the Git child process and hope that VS Code can handle it gracefully.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's actually Visual Studio (not VS Code), but I assume your comment applies either way. But anyway- is it safe to do that? Is it easy to recover with a new checkout command after stopping another in the middle?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. From my experience, just using checkout again works reliably. Git might even roll back automatically if a checkout is aborted, but I’m not sure.

Comment: I've definitely did this a number of times in my experience. Either abort using `Ctrl + C` if able to or kill the process. Your worktree will likely be in a weird in the middle state. Either check out the correct branch you wanted or in the case you're still on your current branch, (force) reset to head to get back to a more stable state

Comment: @JeffMercado - I like how you said "*more* stable state". ;)